# Importing all photos from photo album in swift

Tags: swift, photo

I'm trying to create an app that arranges all the photos from iphone photo album in some order. And so the first thing I must do is to retrieve all the photos from the photo library. Is it possible to do this programmatically in swift?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import AssetsLibrary

let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false) ]
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
photos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
```

And then to display that image: (Possibly in a Collection View)

```
 var photos: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!

     let asset = photos!.object(at: indexPath.row)
            let width: CGFloat = 150
            let height: CGFloat = 150
            let size = CGSize(width:width, height:height)
            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFill, options: nil) { (image, userInfo) -> Void in
                imageView.image = image
     }
```

Comment: Should I put "let" in front of "photos"? And shouldn't "imageView" be declared?

Comment: Also, is it possible to get the date of when the photo was taken? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added the code needed for the first comment. I don't know about the dates i'm sure if you google it you should find something